# CAML query for 'FileRef' does not return relative path

Tags: rest, caml-query, caml, file

I'm having trouble retrieving the relative path of a file using CAML:

```
http://[siteURL]/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('test')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1={"ViewXml":"<View><ViewFields><FieldRef%20Name='FileRef'/></ViewFields><Query></Query></View>"}
```

It returns following results which don't contain the `FileRef` field I'm querying for:

```
<entry m:etag="&quot;2&quot;">
<id>Web/Lists(guid'18bbc395-68ef-4a43-af94-54dfa73fffce')/Items(2)</id>
<category term="SP.Data.Asset_x005f_RightsItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
<link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'18bbc395-68ef-4a43-af94-54dfa73fffce')/Items(2)"/>
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/FirstUniqueAncestorSecurableObject" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="FirstUniqueAncestorSecurableObject" href="Web/Lists(guid'18bbc395-68ef-4a43-af94-54dfa73fffce')/Items(2)/FirstUniqueAncestorSecurableObject"/>
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/RoleAssignments" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="RoleAssignments" href="Web/Lists(guid'18bbc395-68ef-4a43-af94-54dfa73fffce')/Items(2)/RoleAssignments"/>
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/AttachmentFiles" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="AttachmentFiles" href="Web/Lists(guid'18bbc395-68ef-4a43-af94-54dfa73fffce')/Items(2)/AttachmentFiles"/>
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ContentType" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="ContentType" href="Web/Lists(guid'18bbc395-68ef-4a43-af94-54dfa73fffce')/Items(2)/ContentType"/>
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/FieldValuesAsHtml" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="FieldValuesAsHtml" href="Web/Lists(guid'18bbc395-68ef-4a43-af94-54dfa73fffce')/Items(2)/FieldValuesAsHtml"/>
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/FieldValuesAsText" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="FieldValuesAsText" href="Web/Lists(guid'18bbc395-68ef-4a43-af94-54dfa73fffce')/Items(2)/FieldValuesAsText"/>
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/FieldValuesForEdit" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="FieldValuesForEdit" href="Web/Lists(guid'18bbc395-68ef-4a43-af94-54dfa73fffce')/Items(2)/FieldValuesForEdit"/>
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/File" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="File" href="Web/Lists(guid'18bbc395-68ef-4a43-af94-54dfa73fffce')/Items(2)/File"/>
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Folder" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Folder" href="Web/Lists(guid'18bbc395-68ef-4a43-af94-54dfa73fffce')/Items(2)/Folder"/>
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ParentList" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="ParentList" href="Web/Lists(guid'18bbc395-68ef-4a43-af94-54dfa73fffce')/Items(2)/ParentList"/>
<title/>
<updated>2015-11-03T14:37:22Z</updated>
<author>
  <name/>
</author>
<content type="application/xml">
  <m:properties>
    <d:FileSystemObjectType m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:FileSystemObjectType>
    <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:Id>
    <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:ID>
    <d:Modified m:type="Edm.DateTime">2015-10-01T12:40:33</d:Modified>
    <d:CheckoutUserId m:null="true"/>
    <d:EditorId m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:EditorId>
  </m:properties>
</content>
```

This is strange because the same query works fine when I test it in CAML Designer 2013. It also works when I query for other fields, for example document title, ID, etc. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: How are you executing this code? using jquery?

Comment: I'm testing it in Fiddler. Once I get it working I'll be calling it from an MVC controller.

Comment: Can you consider my url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your requirement is to get the `FileRef` of your document, then you can consider following URL.

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('test')/Items?$select=FileRef
```

Just make a GET request to the above URL. If you need more columns, then add them in `$select` operator separated by coma(,).

**Based on the comment:** You need the `<Where>`. You can use `$filter` instead of `<Where>`. If you have time, then have a look on following article.

[CRUD Operation to List Using SharePoint 2013 Rest API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API)

Comment: The problem is that I will be adding a  'where' clause to the query, I don't think the method above has this functionality.

Comment: No. It has. You can use $filter instead of where

Comment: Is it possible to do a recursive query this way? I need to search sub folders as well.

Comment: Above URL will affect all items in library. Does not mater it is in sub folder or root folder. Anyway, these info are missing in your question. It is better if you mention your all requirements in the question.

Comment: I wouldn't give him flack about the requirements.  He asked a question about CAML.  Instead of answering the question he asked, you gave him a workaround.

Comment: His question title & code seem that: to get FileRef is his main requirement. By mentioning it I have started my workaround. When people were trying something in a complex , then I saw others have suggested them a simple way. It's from my observation

Comment: I have combined elements of Atish's URL with my original CAML URL and found that the following URL successfully returns FileRef field: `/GetItems(query=@v1)?$select=fileref&@v1={"ViewXml":"<View><Query></Query></View>"}`